# Sound lag in VLC after I resume from a paused movie

Tags: sound, vlc

I recently made a shift to Linux and this never used to happen when I was using windows. After I pause a movie and I press play again, there is a sound lag. I have to restart the movie every time I have to pause it. Is this fixable?

Comment: Related: [How do I fix VLC sound studdering after pause/resume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457272)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most likely, your videos are poorly encoded.

This doesn't happen with all videos in my experience.  It has to do with there being a large chunk of audio/video data without key-frames or re-syncs of audio and video.

I've seen it occur, but when it happens in VLC it is most often a poorly encoded video.

In order to fix it, re-encode the video with the h264/aac presets, and it should be fine.

Comment: no man, other players don't have such issue, it happens for most video files. It's VLC core issue, even on Android: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android/-/issues/866