# How do I fix VLC sound stuttering after pause/resume?

Tags: sound, video, vlc

On most (maybe all) videos, when played with VLC, pause and resume works fine as long it is only a second or two. When I pause the video for longer, after unpausing, the video plays fine but the audio cuts in and out a few times for several seconds. After these several seconds, playback is normal. It happens with videos which play properly in other video plays, and on every audio device I have tried.

The accepted answer to [VLC no sound after Pause](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276402/vlc-no-sound-after-pause) did not help.

I have had this issue for years I think. I'm currently running VLC 3.0.16 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To fix this issue, in VLC under `Tools` → `Preferences` → `Audio`, disable `Enable Time-Stretching audio` and then save and **restart VLC**.

[image]

**Update**: Not only did this fix the problem I was having with skipping, but later I turned `Enable Time-Stretching audio` back on (so I could speed up videos without the chipmunk effect) and VLC continued to work correctly.

**Update 2**: Since writing the above, I've realized this is, unfortunately, not a permanent fix. The problem will eventually come back if you turn `Enable Time-Stretching audio` back on.  But you can 'fix' it again.

Comment: thanks a lot! was highly annoyed by that and happy to have found a solution.

Comment: This didn´t work for me with VLC 3.0.16 on Ubuntu 22.04. Maybe it was other configuration change?

Comment: OMFG! After years you **finally** land on a solution to this problem that works for me. 1,000 thank yous!

Comment: Neither answer worked for me either on VLC 3.0.18 (and many prior versions, been having this issue more than a year) on Arch Linux.

Comment: it doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 23.10 and vlc 3.0.18

Comment: Alas it worked only the first time I played a video after trying your suggestion. Since then audio stutter with pause/resume is as bad as ever. (I checked and the "Enable Tim-Stretching" is still unchecked.

Comment: Have been bugged by this for years. And now it is resolved.

Answer (score 16):

What worked for me was: `Tools` > `Preferences` > `Audio` > `Output module:` > `ALSA audio output`

Restart VLC and the stuttering after a long pause is gone.

I'm using VLC 3.0.16 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I should add that this is reproducible. If I select pulseaudio (or auto) and restart VLC the stuttering comes back.

Comment: Yep, worked for me.

Comment: I was following along with a tech tutorial video ( using VLC 3.0.16 on 22.04 )....requiring frequent pause / un-pauses and this problem was >extremely< frustrating and annoying to the point that it seriously hampered progress. THANK YOU for sharing your observations and solution. Much appreciated!

Comment: Also worked on 23.04.

Comment: it doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 23.10 and vlc 3.0.18

Comment: didn't fix on ubuntu 22.04

Comment: I think this changed the kind of lag a little bit, but it still happens.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I did the opposite of what other people suggested.

I changed all the values to 111, which is a random value smaller than the default, which is 1200.

And I lowered the clock jitter to 11.

**Probably you need to change only file caching and disk caching, the others should not count.**

It fixed the audio stutter problem.

[image]